# What does SQLite3 -batch CLI option do?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

There is no documentation that I can find beyond the oneliner provided by the command-line utility. It says:

```
-batch               force batch I/O
```

So what's going on here if I pass it a query or multiple queries?

Comment: If you are feeling adventurous, you can try to decode the source code for the sqlite3 command line [here](http://www.sqlite.org/src/artifact/14ff7f660530a52b). The batch option sets a variable called `stdin_is_interactive` to false. The stdin variable has the comment: *"Threat stdin as an interactive input if the following variable is true.  Otherwise, assume stdin is connected to a file or pipe."*

Comment: If you want to answer the question because you've read the source code, please do. I will take a look at the source code, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the `sqlite3` shell is run interactively, it shows a startup message and the `sqlite>` prompt, and (on Windows) tries to converts the input to UTF-8.

If the automatic console detection does not work as intended, it can be overridden with `-batch` or `-interactive`.

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm this is what's happening from the source code (now that I've read it).